# PHP mysql SELECT QUERY with an Or

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id ='$foo' OR id = '$foo2");
```

This doesn't work.

Basically, I want to be able to select it where the id is one variable's value OR another one's.

Thanks.

EDIT: The ID column is numerical.

Comment: missing a `'` in your code. is just a typo?

Comment: Your query is perfect i think value in your variable is going wrong print it and than try

Comment: _"This doesn't work."_ Is that the error you get from MySql? I thought it was a little more verbose on why a given query won't work, but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said and you confirmed, the problem is that you are using string literals to compare to a numeric column. To have it work, the query should look like

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id =$foo OR id = $foo2");
```

**However, this solution has very very bad code smell!**

First off, this is why [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) exists: to be able to write

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN ($foo, $foo2)");
```

And second, are you injecting unescaped strings into your query? If you are, your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/50079)! **Escape and quote** your variables to be safe, like this (in the general case):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN ('%s', '%s')",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($foo),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($foo2));
mysql_query($query);
```

or alternatively like this, since in this specific scenario you know we 're talking about integer values:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (%s, %s)",
                 intval($foo), intval($foo2));
mysql_query($query);
```

*Footnote: I am aware that when using `sprintf` like this, one could also handle integer values by just using `%d` instead if `%s` as the format specifier. However, I believe that proving you are correctly escaping variables should be possible by just looking at one place (the parameter list) instead of multiple places (did I use `intval` on the variable? or maybe I did not, but I 'm using `%d` in the format string so I 'm still OK?). It may sound counter-intuitive, but it's more robust in the face of modifications.*

Comment: @Kakashi: Your edit is wide open to sql injection if `$foo` and/or `$foo2` is malicious.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: How? Please enlighten me.

Comment: string literals are ok to compare with numeric column. but alas I've only 1 vote.

Comment: the same way as any injection works. $id="1 union select password from users";

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: There's an [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) in there, in case you haven't noticed. `"1 union select password from users"` would be converted to just `1`.

Comment: intvals are in the 4th I am talking of 3rd

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot the last ' character

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id ='$foo' OR id = '$foo2'");
```

but because the id column is numerical, you should use:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = $foo OR id = $foo2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = %s OR id = %s", $foo, $foo2));
```

I recommend you use mysql_error() for get mysql errors(if exists).

```
mysql_query( .. ) or die('Erro:'.mysql_error());
```

the mysql_error returns the last error occurred in mysql.