# How to add many WHERE constraints when updating a mysql table using php?

Tags: php, mysqli, constraints

How can I add multiple constraints after the WHERE part of the UPDATE MySQL table statement? Is this possible? I have tried separating the constraints using commas. Thank you.

```
    $update_error = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET error_level='3'
                    WHERE errors <= '650', errors > '200'");
```

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182896/php-mysql-select-query-with-an-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add logical operator (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html) which will describe to MYSQL what is the connection between conditions:

It will look like this

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET error_level='3' WHERE errors <= '650' AND errors > '200'");
```

or this

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET error_level='3' WHERE errors <= '650' OR errors > '200'");
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL :

```
WHERE errors <= '650'AND errors > '200'
```

You could also use BETWEEN ( I find this easier to read later )

```
WHERE errors BETWEEN 200 AND 650
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users SET error_level='3' WHERE errors <= '650' AND errors > '200'
```

Comment: You might in words point out the difference between a comma and an `AND`...